# Writing to .csv data obtained by API calls while using multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, csv, google-cloud-platform

I have a quite peculiar problem. I have a collection of CSVs with various information inside them. What I'm doing is: loading a singular CSV, making a call to Google's Perspective API to analyze the text of a specific field of such CSV, appending the results to a new column, and saving the updated CSV.

Since the API calls take a while, I'm trying to use multithreading to process different CSV with each thread.

My process is divided into three different functions:

```
query_perspective(text, languages = None, api_client)
```

takes in input a text and returns a dictionary of scores given to the text by the Perspective API. This function also handles exceptions and errors by stopping the execution for a certain time in case of certain errors or skipping the execution altogether in case of others. Then,

```
parse_perspective_scores(scores)
```

takes in input the dictionary of scores given by the previous function and parses the information I need, and

```
process_csv(slice1, slice2)
```

takes in input a subset of CSVs from my input directory (defined by slice1 and slice2), loads each of them as a Pandas dataframe, applies the two previous functions to the text I care about, appends the results as a new column, and saves the updated CSVs to a different directory (also, the last function doesn't actually return anything except some print statements, it just saves the CSVs)

This works fine when run normally, but what I would like to do is use multithreading so that each thread can work on a different subset of CSVs, hopefully speeding up the process considerably. I'm quite new to multithreading/multiprocessing and using APIs in general and I feel like I don't really know what I'm doing. For now, I came up with this (supposing 4 threads):

```
slices = (
(0, 100),
(100, 200),
(200, 300),
(300, 400))
 

def runner():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    for (slice1, slice2) in slices:
        executor.submit(process_csv, slice1, slice2)
```

When calling `runner()`, the code actually runs and the print statements appear, but I keep getting errors relative to the API calls which don't happen when running the function without multithreading, such as `[SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC]`, or `[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER]`, and it crashes my kernel after a while. What I'd like to know is if this could be caused by the multithreading function I'm using, and in case if someone could provide me with a template of a multithread function to utilize in such cases.

I can provide the code of the functions if needed, but my real question is if the code above is (in theory) correct to save these CSVs while using different threads. I can try to work out the errors I get by myself once I get the multithreading procedure down (or post a new question focused on that, at least), but as of now, I don't even know if that is correct.

Thank you in advance to everyone who might answer this and have a good day!

Comment: Hey everyone, OP here, don't know if this might help someone but I managed to solve the errors in the multithreading function (which works by the way) by utilizing a wrapper for the API: this is leading me to think that the error was caused by the fact that I may have wrongly built the API_CLIENT in my code